# what kind of object/variable should i pass to this function

Tags: jquery

I am using this plugin called magnific popup. but I do not know how to dynamically pass data to the magnificPopup({});

it uses something like this

```
$('#show').magnificPopup({
                items: [
                  {
                    src: 'path-to-image-1.jpg'
                  },
                  {
                    src: 'http://vimeo.com/123123',
                    type: 'iframe' // this overrides default type
                  },
                  {
                    src: $('<div>Dynamically created element</div>'),
                    type: 'inline'
                  },
                  {
                    src: '<div>HTML string</div>',
                    type: 'inline'
                  }
            });
```

I am not sure if the items object is an array or JSON ..

so far I have manage to make my own array with

```
    itemsPath[i][0] = 1 //id
    itemsPath[i][1] = 'a.jpg'
    itemsPath[i][0] = 1
    itemsPath[i][1] = 'u.jpg''
    itemsPath[i][0] = 1
    itemsPath[i][1] = 'e.jpg'
    itemsPath[i][0] = 1
    itemsPath[i][1] = 'r.jpg''
    itemsPath[i][0] = 2
    itemsPath[i][1] = 'y.jpg''
```

it is a multidimensional array where I store the id and the image file name .. 
my question is how can I pass it in the magnificPopup({}); function above??

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

magnificPopup is expecting an array of objects for items.  So, you'll need to translate your 2 dimensional array into an array of objects.  http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/c2k5af4j/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var itemsPath = [[1,'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats/1'],[1,'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats/2'],[1,'http://lorempixel.com/100/200/cats/3'],[1,'http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats/4'],[2,'http://lorempixel.com/40/200/cats/5']];
//    var itemsPath = [[1,'a.jpg'],[1,'u.jpg'],[1,'e.jpg'],[1,'r.jpg'],[2,'y.jpg']];

    var items = [];
    for (i = 0; i < itemsPath.length; i++) {
        items.push({
            src: itemsPath[i][1]
        });
    }

    $('#open-popup').magnificPopup({
        items: items,
        gallery: {
          enabled: true
        },
        type: 'image' 
    });
});
```

There are lots of ways to use magnificPopup, and this is just one example.